# Can't install Bootstrap 3 Datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I'm been mad because I can't install this Bootstrap 3 Datepicker in mt project: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#manual.
It show me the little hand to click, but is not working, the calendar not appear.
Someone can help me please?
Here is my code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="it"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Stili CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pages.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-assistenza-audi">
          <span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></i></span>Prenota
      </button>
      
<!--modal-permuta-->
<div id="modal-assistenza-audi" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Prenotazione Appuntamento</h4>
   </div><!-- /modal-header -->
   <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- !FORM -->
    <div id="form-assistenza-audi">
     <form id="assistenza-audi" method="post" class="form">

      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                   <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(function () {
                     $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
                 });
             </script>

                   </div>
      </div>
      <br />
     </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /FORM -->
   </div><!-- /modal-body -->
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Invia</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
   </div><!-- /modal-footer -->
  </div><!-- /modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /modal-permuta -->
</body>
```

I Got error saying like this in console.
[image]

Comment: I also have these scripts at the bottom:

'<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>'

Comment: check all js and css is loaded or not.

Comment: if js/vendor/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js is in bottom. Then what js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js doing in head section ?

Comment: put  all .js in foot or bottom part